# What are the criteria for Community♦ to bump a question?

Tags: support

I direct your attention to this question: [What does it mean when the connectivity icons in the status bar go white/gray?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/9642/what-does-it-mean-when-the-connectivity-icons-in-the-status-bar-go-white-gray)

This question was recently bumped by Community♦ to the front page.

I *thought* the Community♦ user only bumped questions that didn't have upvoted, accepted answers.

This question has:

- Over 40 votes on the question
- Over 40 votes on the **accepted** answer
- Almost 18,000 views

Why did this get bumped?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually a result of a different scenario, but from the front page it's effectively indistinguishable from a normal Community♦ bump. What *actually* happened here was:

- An [incredibly juvenile and pointless "answer"](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/41362/981) was posted by a new account
- Said account was destroyed, and the post deleted

In this situation, Community♦ (evidently) becomes the "owner" of the last modification to the post since it would otherwise end up being attributed to a non-existent account. In fact, clicking on the timestamp for the last activity on the front page will link you directly to the deleted answer.

Comment: Well then. Unfortunately, three deleted answers on that question are from deleted accounts, so the auto-protect didn't kick in. Perhaps it should be applied manually.

Comment: @user267: I agree. I just went and protected it.

Comment: My fault not looking at the deleted answers. I guess it's because it was below another question that _had_ been bumped. I'll accept this as soon as the timer runs out.